# TypeScript: Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this really sipmple ProviderAlert component. It renders the alert based on the props being passed from the parent.

```
 JSX.Element | undefined => {
    return (alertIsOpen ? (
        <Alert status={alertStatus} w="80%" style={alertStyle}>
            <AlertIcon />
            {title}
            <CloseButton
                position="absolute"
                right="8px"
                top="8px"
                onClick={(): void => {
                    setAlertIsOpen(false)
                }}
            />
        </Alert>
    ) : undefined)
```

I have tried adding parenthesis to the return statement of the parent but it's not working. This is an example of how I'm rendering the different alerts in the parent component:

```
       {credentialsModalIsOpen && (
            <ProviderAlert
                title="Connection Successful!"
                alertStatus="success"
                alertIsOpen={true}
                setAlertIsOpen={(): void => setCredentialsModalIsOpen(false)}
            />
        )}
```

I have also tried changing `undefined` to `null` in the ProviderAlert component. It works, but the linter forces me to "use undefined instead of null".

Comment: Could you just be a bit more clear what is the actual issue you are having? Is the component not rendering correctly or are you getting a different error.

Comment: The IDE and the linter both throw the error that is the title of this question

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the top component with this. You shouldn't ever be returning undefined. Undefined is reserved for when a value has not been given a value, you should instead use null.

```
interface Props {
  title: string;
  alertStatus: string;
  alertIsOpen: boolean;
  setAlertIsOpen: () => void;
}

const ProviderAlert: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  if (!alertIsOpen) {
    return null;
  }    

  return (
    <Alert status={alertStatus} w="80%" style={alertStyle}>
      <AlertIcon />
      {title}
      <CloseButton
        position="absolute"
        right="8px"
        top="8px"
        onClick={(): void => setAlertIsOpen(false)} />
    </Alert>
  );
}

export default ProviderAlert;
```

Comment: This is the same thing with a different syntax. It doesn't solve the root of the problem: The linter doesn't allow me to use null, but if I use undefined it crashes.

Comment: Without having access to your code it is difficult to debug as what I have posted above works. It is incorrect to use undefined, I am not sure why your linter is throwing an error for null if you were to share that might shed some light on the issue